How to define a set without using itself in its definition?
I am trying to construct a set using set builder notation but I am not succeeding.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary finite sets, and let $Z\subsetneq Y$ be non-empty. Then, let $F=Y^X$ be the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.
Fix any element $x^*$. Then, I want to define a set $Q(x^*)\subseteq F$ that satisfies the following properties:

For every element $y\in Z$, the set $Q(x^*)$ contains exactly one function $f:X\to Y$ satisfying $f(x^*)=y$.
For every element $y’\in Y\backslash Z$, the set $Q$ contains no function $f:X\to Y$ satisfying $f(x^*)=y’$.

I have played around with different ways to write the set $Q$ using set builder notation, but all of them seem to be self-referential in the sense that the set that I am defining is part of its own definition, a feature that is making me uncomfortable. I suspect that the reason why this might be happening is that there are many sets $Q$ satisfying the aforementioned properties (1) and (2).
One possibility I have been toying around with is the following:
\begin{gather}
Q(x^*)=\big\{f\in F\mid[(\forall y\in Z)(\exists !f\in Q(x^*))(f(x^*)=y)]\wedge[(\forall y’\in Y\backslash Z)(\nexists f\in Q(x^*))(f(x^*)=y’)]\big\}
\end{gather}
What makes me uncomfortable of the above definition is the fact that that the set $Q(x^*)$, which is the set being defined, appears in its own definition. This makes me think that my definition is not legit.
Therefore, how would you go about defining the set I am interested in using set builder notation?

The problem is that you "define" $Q(x^*)$ with two properties that absolutely do not guaratee existence nor uniqueness at first sight, so there is no direct unique way to define it. You can define the set of all $Q \subset F$ that satisfy these properties but you will have to pick arbitrary elements in it to obtain an example of a possible $Q(x^*)$.
We can easily check that such a set always exists by taking the set of constant fonctions with value in $Z$ for example,
$$
Q = \{f \in F|\forall (x_1,x_2) \in X^2, f(x_1) = f(x_2) \land f(x_1) \in Z\}
$$
Notice it doesn't even depend on the choice of $x^*$. But there are a lot of other possibilities since the wanted properties for $Q(x^*)$ only depend on the $f(x^*)$ for $f$ in this set.
